# Ubuntu password prompt freezes, have to hard reboot. On 22.04 Studio

Tags: ubuntu, usb, passwords, freeze, prompt

I have a wireless USB mouse and keyboard and randomly when booting the password prompt is frozen, no blinking cursor.
Seems a random annoyance thing.
Thinking the USB port is getting claimed or not loaded.
A trawle round the net doesn't seem to give any answers to this particular problem.
Always works after the reboot.
Many thanks.

Comment: Why not test with *wired* peripherals, since you think that *might* be a cause??

Comment: I don't have wired keyboard as this has worked for years. What changed?